# How to document Visual Basic with Doxygen

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6, documentation, doxygen

I am trying to use some Doxygen filter for Visual Basic in Windows.

I started with Vsevolod Kukol filter, based on gawk.
There are not so many directions.
So I started using his own commented VB code [VB6Module.bas](https://github.com/sevoku/Doxygen-VB-Filter/blob/master/samples/ClassicVB/VB6Module.bas) and, by means of his [vbfilter.awk](https://github.com/sevoku/Doxygen-VB-Filter/blob/master/vbfilter.awk), I issued:

```
gawk -f vbfilter.awk VB6Module.bas
```

This outputs a C-like code on stdin. Therefore I redirected it to a file with:

```
gawk -f vbfilter.awk VB6Module.bas>awkout.txt
```

I created this Doxygen `test.cfg` file:

```
PROJECT_NAME      = "Test"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  = test
GENERATE_LATEX    = NO
GENERATE_MAN      = NO
GENERATE_RTF      = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES  = NO
INPUT             = awkout.txt
QUIET             = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF = NO
SEARCHENGINE      = NO
```

To produce the documentation I issued:

```
doxygen test.cfg
```

Doxygen complains as the "name 'VB6Module.bas' supplied as the second argument in the \file statement is not an input file." I removed the comment `@file VB6Module.bas` from `awkout.txt`. The warning stopped, but in both cases the documentation produced was just a single page with the project name.

I tried also the alternative filter by Basti Grembowietz in Python [vbfilter.py](http://home.in.tum.de/~grembowi/vbfilter/vbfilter.py). Again without documentation, again producing errors and without any useful output.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the INPUT_FILTER option and let Doxygen run the script for you.

Comment: I posted quite a long comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trials and errors I solved the problem.

I was unable to convert a `.bas` file in a format such that I can pass it to Doxygen as input. 
Anyway, following  @doxygen user suggestions, I was able to create a Doxygen config file such that it can interpret the `.bas` file comments properly.

Given the file [VB6Module.bas](https://github.com/sevoku/Doxygen-VB-Filter/blob/master/samples/ClassicVB/VB6Module.bas) (by the Doxygen-VB-Filter author, Vsevolod Kukol), commented with Doxygen style adapted for Visual Basic, I wrote the Doxygen config file, `test.cfg`, as follows:

```
PROJECT_NAME      = "Test"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  = test
GENERATE_LATEX    = NO
GENERATE_MAN      = NO
GENERATE_RTF      = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES  = NO
INPUT             = readme.md VB6Module.bas
QUIET             = YES
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF = NO
SEARCHENGINE      = NO
FILTER_PATTERNS   = "*.bas=vbfilter.bat"
```

where:

- `readme.md` is any Markdown file that can used as the main documentation page.
- `vbfilter.bat` contains:

  @echo off
  gawk.exe -f vbfilter.awk "%1%"
- [vbfilter.awk](https://github.com/sevoku/Doxygen-VB-Filter/blob/master/vbfilter.awk) by the filter author is assumed to be in the same folder as the input files to be documented and obviously  [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) should be in the path.

Running:

```
doxygen test.cfg
```

everything is smooth, apart two apparently innocuous warnings:

```
gawk: vbfilter.awk:528: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `[' 
gawk: vbfilter.awk:528: warning: escape sequence `\]' treated as plain `]'
```

Now `test\html\index.html` contains the proper documentation as extracted by the ".bas" and the Markdown files.

Comment: Does this work for `.cls` files too? Or does this only work for procedural code?

Comment: @StefanFalk: I haven't tried (or I did and forgot). Anyway, for sure `vbfilter.awk` accepts and parses `.cls` and, by updating the config file with `.cls` files, you can pass the filtered input to doxygen. Then I don't know if any specific issue might arise.

Comment: Okay thank you. I've tried it and it parses of course but the problem is that a single folder is treated as `package` that contains all functions after running doxygen. That means functions from `ModuleName.bas` and `ClassName.cls` will be thrown together. A simple solution might be moving all files into seperate folders and same named. This would create separate documentations for each file and a function entry e.g. would look like `Public ClassName.FunctionName() As Integer`.

Comment: Please share your solution as an answer if you find one

Answer (score 1):

Alright I did some work:

You can download [this .zip file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30731675/VBADoxy.zip). It contains:

- **MakeDoxy.bas** The macro that makes it all happen
- **makedoxy.cmd** A shell script that will be executed by MakeDoxy
- **configuration** Folder that contains doxygen and gawk binaries which are needed to create the doxygen documentation as well as some additional filtering files which were already used by the OP.
- **source** Folder that contains example source code for doxygen

---

## How To Use:

**Note:** I tested it with Excel 2010

1. Extract **VBADoxy.zip** somehwere (referenced as `<root>` from now on)
2. Import **MakeDoxy.bas** into your VBA project. 
   *You can also import the files from **source** or use your own doxygen-documented VBA code files but you'll need at least one documented file in the same VBA project.*
   [image]
3. Add "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" or higher to your VBA Project References (did not test it with lower versions). It's needed for the export-part ([VBProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443985%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [VBComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443982%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)).
   [image]
4. Run macro *MakeDoxy*

---

## What is going to happen:

1. You will be asked for the `<root>` folder.
2. You will be asked if you want to delete `<root>\source` afterwards
    *It is okay to delete those files. They **will not** be removed from your VBA Project.*
3. *MakeDoxy* will export all `.bas`, `cls` and `.frm` files to location:
   `<root>\source\<modulename>\<modulename>(.bas|.cls|.frm)`
4. `cmd.exe`will be commanded to run `makedoxy.cmd` and delete `<root>\source` if you've chosen that way which alltogether will result in your desired documentation.

A logfile `MakeDoxy.bas.log`will be re-created each time *MakeDoxy* is executed.

You can play with `configuration\vbdoxy.cfg` a little if you want to change doxygens behavior.

There is still some room for improvements but I guess this is something one can work with.

Comment: +1 nice work, I have not VB handy now but will test it as soon as I can.

Comment: Alright :) I think it's still not perfect but now it does not throw together the modules. Maybe this could also be prevented by changing the doxy .cfg file but I didn't find anything yet. But this way one can use it as a "export all module files at once"-tool too :D

Comment: The link to the zip file is broken.  [this .zip file][1] [1]: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30731675/VBADoxy.zip

Comment: @displayname Hi, sorry to bother you with this, but would it be possible to re-upload the Zip File or edit the answer to copy it's actual contents (at least the feasible parts) into the answer?

Comment: @L8n Sorry but I'm afraid I do not have this file anymore.