# Problems with Doxygen and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, doxygen, gawk, doxywizard

I tried both way described in [Documenting Visual Basic with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260408/documenting-visual-basic-with-doxygen/15292478#15292478) to generate a documentation for a Visual Basic .NET project I have. But all that appears is just a page with 1 button "Main page".

Could somebody of the experts tell me exactly where I have to place all the files I need to run the filter properly? Also, which of the Doxygen parameters I need to set to run it? The best way for me would be to use the XML file which is generated by SharpDevelop to produce the documentation. But also a solution to use the single vb-files would be okay.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear on what two choices you tried.

I do not think I used the methods on the page referenced. However, in case it is helpful I did get Doxygen to document my VB script using XML comments. For this I had to edit my code, rather than tell Doxygen how to parse pre-existing comments. Here is an example. (It can be indented at the correct level.)

```
''' <summary> First line of class overview.
''' <para></para>
''' Methods include; ...
''' </summary>
```